# Get line number on which function returned

Tags: go

Is it possible to get the line number on which a function returned from the calling scope?

Example:

```
func callee() error {
  if cond {
    return errors.New("whoops!")
  }
  return nil
}

func caller() {
  // Possible to retrieve the line number of callee return here?
  callee()
}
```

I assume that's not possible, since it should be already removed from the stack, but maybe it's still cached somewhere?

The use case is that I have a HTTP handler and I'd like to log the line and filename on which the error was returned, without having to litter the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to automatically acquire the line where the last return was executed.

However, with a small helper one can have:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
)

func here(s string, args ...interface{}) error {
        _, fname, fline, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        h := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d: ", fname, fline)
        return fmt.Errorf(h+s, args...)
}

func foo(i int) error {
        if i == 2 {
                return here("cannot handle %d", i) // line 16
        }

        if i%3 == 0 {
                return here("also cannot handle %d", i) // line 20
        }

        return nil
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println(foo(2))
        fmt.Println(foo(3))
        fmt.Println(foo(4))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/-srHyxezKW)

---

Output:

```
/tmpfs/gosandbox-92c2a0f2_32bdf9d9_3c7d2a0a_80ba8510_f68d9721/prog.go:16: cannot handle 2
/tmpfs/gosandbox-92c2a0f2_32bdf9d9_3c7d2a0a_80ba8510_f68d9721/prog.go:20: also cannot handle 3
<nil>
```

Comment: +1 I just wrote some similar code and was about to post it as an answer, only to see there was no longer any need.

Comment: Yes, I already considered the wrapping function option. Will use it then, if there seems to be no better alternative.