# _file_ or _line_ similar in golang

Tags: c, go

is there any function in go that is similar like `"_file_"` or `"_line_"` in go, to know who is calling a specific function during run time? In C we have the `"_file_"` line that can be called as macros. How to do this in go?

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17543546/720999)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using the `log` package, you can instruct the logger to [prefix the entries with various information](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants). You'll likely be most interested in the `Lshortfile` constant, which will result in prefixes along the lines of `d.go:23`. Alternatively, there is `Llongfile` which prints the file's full path (such as `/a/b/c/d.go:23`).

If you don't want to use the `log` package, you could also use [`runtime.Caller()`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller), which is what the log package uses internally. It's not as straight forward as the C macros, but you could hide it behind a function (and specify the correct call depth). You can [see how the log package is implemented](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go) for an example (line 140).

Comment: To be explicit: `log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)` and then `log.Println("Error!")` will print "myfile.go:8: Error!"

Answer (score 14):

(1) Write a brief function that calls runtime.Caller()

(2) Call that function everywhere you want to access the source code file and line number at run time.

Example:

```
import "runtime"

func file_line() string {
    _, fileName, fileLine, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    var s string
    if ok {
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", fileName, fileLine)
    } else {
        s = ""
    }
    return s
}
```

Note: pass 1 to Caller() so that it returns the number of the line where file_line() is called, instead of where runtime.Caller() is called.

```
fmt.Println(file_line())  // Prints this file and line number.
```

Comment: For short file name use `path.Base(fileName)`

Answer (score 2):

See the `runtime` and `runtime.debug` packages and in particular the `Stack`, `PrintStack` or `Caller`[functions](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug).

> Stack formats a stack trace of the calling goroutine into buf and returns the number of bytes written to buf. If all is true, Stack formats stack traces of all other goroutines into buf after the trace for the current goroutine.

If you are compiling with debug information, then this will should contain the line number in source

Answer (score 0):

```
//import ( "log" "strings" "bytes" "path/filepath" )
func SRC_FILE() string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    log.New(&buf, "", log.Lshortfile).Output(2, "")//2=>CALLER 
    __FILE_LINE__ := strings.TrimSpace(buf.String())
    __FILE__ := strings.TrimRight(__FILE_LINE__, ":1234567890")
    return __FILE__
}

func SRC_DIR() string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    log.New(&buf, "", log.Llongfile).Output(2, "")//2=>CALLER
    __FILE_LINE__ := strings.TrimSpace(buf.String())
    __FILE__ := strings.TrimRight(__FILE_LINE__, ":1234567890")
    __DIR__ := filepath.Dir(__FILE__)
    return __DIR__
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SRC_FILE())//analogous to __FILE__
    fmt.Println(SRC_DIR()) //analogous to __DIR__
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/3nvgknX96RO
When you run it on `go.dev/play` your code is run as `prog.go`